# How to send email throug smtp in laravel 5.5

Tags: node.js, laravel, reactjs

I want to email for client in my project when i try to mail the client it shows the following error (Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "tlsl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #178257984]) i google it but not found any solution any body help thank in advance.
this is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: make your google account to allow access for less secure apps : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Try with port 25.

Comment: yes already set less secure apps

Comment: not working with port 25

Comment: Try changing the encryption type to ssl.

Answer (score 0):

Problem must be related cahced config, Can you try again send email after clear config,

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention when you use gmail as smtp server. It has 2 ports: `465` and `587`. If you choose 587, you need to use ssl like encryption, and if you choose 465, use tls. After that, you need to configure your gmail account to allow less secure apps: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255.

Don't forget restart your laravel server each time your update your `.env` config file.